# How to transform a armature into a metarig

Tags: animation, armature, bones, pose-mode

Newbie Here, I'd like to know how I can transform the armature of my model into a metarig

Comment: That can be done, but it's a tedious task that involves many steps for each bone and a good deal of understanding how rigify works.  You might be better off creating a custom metargi from scratch.  There are some online tutorials that might help you, like [this one](https://youtu.be/o6_AzySr64c)  You can find the basic instructions in the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/metarigs.html)

Comment: If the armature is a generated rigify rig you can restore the meta rig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can go to pose mode, select the first bone of a connected chain, and set its Rigify type to one of the Rigify presets on the dropdown list.

Any number of chains can be combined in any combination and parentship structure, but some Rigify types require one exact number and structure of bones.

The Types requirements are listed in the Blender Manual, as Marty said.

[image]

[image]